# DOCKER How to update update Hosts file from dockerfile or right in container?

Tags: docker, hosts, dockerfile

Is there a clean solution without any tricks?
Trying to find but cannot see some predefined documented approach for such simple operation

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create docker image with own hosts file as docker with override it when it create container from image. But you can use --add-host option in [`docker run`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) command or you can modify hosts file in container after start (since Docker 1.2)

Comment: Thanks. That works. Just found -add-host option right after creation a question here :) But did not find how to delete a question here :)

Comment: @user3057036 it's a good question to have answered here; other people will look for it.